# Expl3 syntax highlighting for Gedit

Tags: expl3, editors, gedit

Does anyone have a syntax pattern for `gedit`, that will correctly highlight `Expl3` code? I.e., something that will recognize that the entirety of `\cs_new:Npn` is a command sequence—although highlighting the `:Npn` suffix differently might not be a bad idea.

Thank you.